# A generic which is value is a collection

Tags: swift, generics

I wish to be able to create a class with a generic type, and make an extension for the use case in which the generic is a Dictionary.

E.G:

```swift
public final class AtomicCollection<WrappedValue> {

}
```

I want to be able to implement all the methods a Dictionary/Array/Set has, for example `func removeAll()`.

I tried to do that with an `extension` so:

```swift
extension AtomicCollection where WrappedValue == Dictionary {

}
```

The problem is, I get the following error:

`Reference to generic type 'Dictionary' requires arguments in <...>`

This will result in the fact that I need to mention the type of which the `Key` and the `Value` are fora `Dictionary`, `Element` is for an `Array` etc..

I want to be able to create a generic constraint for **ALL Dictionaries, Arrays and Sets**.

Any idea?

Comment: You have to specify the type arguments of the dictionary, i.e. what kind of Dictionary is needs to be (e.g. `Dictionary<Int, String>`). I'm not sure if it's possible to abstract over that, too

Comment: Maybe you could explain how you want to use the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing is you're not asking for Dictionary. Your title captures your intent: all collections. So that's what you want:

```
extension AtomicCollection where WrappedValue: Collection {}
```

If you need to be able to call `removeAll()`, the protocol is [RangeReplaceableCollection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection) (which also implies Collection):

```
extension AtomicCollection where WrappedValue: RangeReplaceableCollection {}
```

You just need to pick (or create) a protocol that has the methods you need for this group of algorithms. That's the whole point of protocols: to define a set of methods that algorithms can operate on.

There are quite a few protocols related to collection-like things. You can find an overview of them in [Sequence and Collection Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence-and-collection-protocols).

Comment: I was hoping there might be better way of doing this beside subgrouping different functionalities into a protocol and conform to that.

On the other hand, this does stand to reason as POP in swift refers to functional programming.

Thank you!

Comment: Do note that the restrictions on specializing with generic types (like Dictionary) is just a current limitation of the language. While in this case, a protocol would be the correct tool, some day Swift may support what you're describing directly (there are many other cases where it would be useful, particularly for Optional). See the Future Directions section of https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0361-bound-generic-extensions.md#future-directions for the latest thinking on that.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can do this by specifying generic conditions for each function in the extension, but not for the whole extension itself:

```
extension AtomicCollection {
    func removeAll<T1, T2>() where WrappedValue == Dictionary<T1, T2> {
    }
}
```